# Chip antenna and uFL/SMA connector routing

Tags: pcb, rf, matching

I created a PCB on which, depending on the mounting variant, I would like to place a Johanson Technology 0868AT43A0020E antenna or a uFL / SMA connector for an external antenna. I have a few questions:

1. Should I put any element before the matching circuit (C3, L2, C4)?
2. Should the element (R9/R8) that will be the jumper selecting the RF output be 0 Ω or a capacitor?
3. There is a route in the antenna documentation like in my picture, can it be the mirror image (out from left side)?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Even a track stub on the antenna track may funtion as an inductor, so ideally you wouldn't have sharp corners or stubs along the antenna track. Maybe the resistors could share a pad and would be in 45 degree angle from the track (90 from each other)
2. Resistor is fine and the simplest solution. You can get away with a capacitor, but you need to consider all combinations, parasitics and non-idealities.
3. Yes, it can be the mirror image too.

Btw, I would keep the fiducial out from the antenna area, as it has a copper area.

Also, often you can have a wider section of ground plane in between the antenna and other components, even if it means having a longer antenna track. Check the application note for antenna track distance to gnd plane etc recommendations.